# How to clear cache ssas tabular

Tags: ssas, tabular

I had some problem with ssas model. becous the deployed model did not show the changes. I wana clear chache hope to solve the issue. But I do not know how to clear chache.

Answer (score 0):

To clear cache on Tabular (and MultiDimensional), you can run this XMLA command:

```
<ClearCache xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
    <Object>
        <DatabaseID>MGROI_dev</DatabaseID>
    </Object>
</ClearCache>
```

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/clear-the-analysis-services-caches?view=asallproducts-allversions